# Iterating a condition for a column for finding other columns values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate birth column to find particular age groups to count category items of these groups.

My dataset is like below.

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'birth': ['1/12/1980', '2/6/1992', '6/6/1975',
'6/3/2000'], 'problem':['cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1' , 'cat1']})


    birth   problem
0   1/12/1980   cat3
1   2/6/1992    cat2
2   6/6/1975    cat1
3   6/3/2000    cat1
..   ......     ....
15488  9/9/2010    cat55
```

proper output may be like:

> Young( 1990-2019) : Cat1: 55, cat2:154, cat3:84, cat6:5554
>
> YoungAdult: (1990-1975): Cat1: 99, cat2: 5121, cat3: 5445
>
> MiddleAged: (1975 and before) : cat1: 99, cat2: 545, cat82: 644

deleted punctuation, convert type to string and tried something like below:

```
for i in range(len(yas2)):
    yas3.append(int(yas2[i][-4:]))
```

then iterate the conditions but i cant integrate and count problems column.

Comment: `1/12/1980` is `1. December` or `12. January` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), binning by [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) and last get counts per groups by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'birth': ['1/12/1980', '2/6/1992', '6/6/1975','6/3/2000'], 
                     'problem':['cat3', 'cat2', 'cat1' , 'cat1']})

data['birth'] = pd.to_datetime(data['birth'], dayfirst=True)

bins = [0, 1975, 1990, 2019]
labels= ['MiddleAged','YoungAdult','Young']
data['bins'] = pd.cut(data['birth'].dt.year, bins=bins, labels=labels)

print (data)
       birth problem        bins
0 1980-12-01    cat3  YoungAdult
1 1992-06-02    cat2       Young
2 1975-06-06    cat1  MiddleAged
3 2000-03-06    cat1       Young

df = data.groupby(['bins','problem']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
         bins problem  count
0  MiddleAged    cat1      1
1  YoungAdult    cat3      1
2       Young    cat1      1
3       Young    cat2      1
```